# Akka Remote producing weird java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: scala, akka, akka-http

I am playing around with Akka remote. A simple example using Akka 2.5.23 works fine. If I add the functionality in the real development project I face a very strange issue:

```
Uncaught error from thread [RemoteSystem-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-6]: Receiver class akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract serializationInformation()Lakka/serialization/Serialization$Information; of interface akka.actor.ActorRefProvider., shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[RemoteSystem]
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: Receiver class akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method abstract serializationInformation()Lakka/serialization/Serialization$Information; of interface akka.actor.ActorRefProvider.
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.serializationInformation(Serialization.scala:166)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.akka$serialization$Serialization$$withTransportInformation(Serialization.scala:172)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.akka$serialization$Serialization$$deserializeByteArray(Serialization.scala:231)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization$$anonfun$deserialize$2.apply(Serialization.scala:221)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at akka.serialization.Serialization.deserialize(Serialization.scala:213)
    at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.deserialize(MessageSerializer.scala:30)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$lzycompute$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.payload$1(Endpoint.scala:64)
    at akka.remote.DefaultMessageDispatcher.dispatch(Endpoint.scala:82)
    at akka.remote.EndpointReader$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:982)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive$$$capture(Actor.scala:539)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala)
    at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:446)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:612)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:581)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:268)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:229)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:241)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

I also tried to change the serializers by the following configuration:

```
  akka {
    actor {
      provider = remote
      serializers {
          proto = "akka.remote.serialization.ProtobufSerializer"
          kryo = "com.twitter.chill.akka.AkkaSerializer"
      }
      serialization-bindings {
          "java.io.Serializable" = kryo
      }
      enable-additional-serialization-bindings = on
      allow-java-serialization = off
    }
    remote {
      enabled-transports = ["akka.remote.netty.tcp"]
      netty.tcp {
        hostname = "127.0.0.1"
        port = 2552
      }
   }
  }
```

I carefully checked that all Akka jars are of the same version.

Any help to diagnose and solve the problem is highly appreciated.

Comment: I dig deeper into the problem. My Java class path contains another project that depends on Akka 2.4.20. I used the maven dependency exclusion to remove these versions and checked carefully with maven dependency tree. If I downgrade Akka to 2.4.20 in the project then it works. That points me to the conclusion that the Akka dynamic dependency resolution to load at runtime fails to pick up the proper versions. Hard to say if it is a Java classpath problem or an Akka problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Apache Beam brings in Apache Flink, which relies on an older version of Akka. The dynamic extension loading process of Akka silently loads the older version, which leads to a crash. The fast solution was to downgrade Akka to the same version that Apache Flink is using.